# Why is the orbit $\cal{O}_x$ of the circle group a circle with radius $|x|$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$. What is the orbit $\cal{O}_x$ of $x\in \mathbb{C}$ under $\mathbb{T}$?

Comment: Complex multiplication by a complex number of unit length is a rotation

Comment: @JohnMcGee But no one even hasn't specified what is the action of $\mathbb{T}$ ;)

Comment: I have trouble showing that, $\cal{O}_x=\{y=gx: g\in\mathbb{T}\}$ defines a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orbit $\mathcal O_x$ is
$$\mathcal O_x=\{xy:y\in\Bbb T\}$$

Let $S_x=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=|x|\}$ be the circle centered at $0$ with radius $|x|$. Let's show that these sets are the same.

Indeed, if $w\in\mathcal O_x$ then there exist some $y\in\Bbb T$ such that $w=xy$. Then
$$|w|=|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|=|x|\cdot 1=|x|$$
therefore, $w\in S_x$.

Reciprocally, if $w\in S_x$, then
$$w=x\cdot\frac{w}{x}$$
but since $|w/x|=1$, the number $w/x$ is in $\Bbb T$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.